# Given W is a solution space for Ax=0 and dim(w) is 3 find rank(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

Given W is a solution space for Ax=0 and A is a 4x4 matrix and Dim(W)=3 determine the rank of A?

Isn't it just 3? It seems too simple if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rank-Nullity Theorem. Namely $\text{dim}(V) = \text{dim}(N(A)) + \text{dim}(R(A)) $. Where $V$ is the whole space, $R(A) $ is the range of the mapping $A$  and $N(A) $ is the kern of $A$ i.e. solution space of $Ax=0$. So $N(A) =W$.  Since $A$ is 4 by 4 matrix $\text{dim} (V) =4$. A simple calculation gives us $\text{dim}(R(A)) = 1$. The dimension of the range of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A$ so it is $1$.